# Question about Conditional Probability and Bayes Law

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

[image]
[image]

---

I am currently reading [Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kfoF.png) and have encountered this passage.

Now my question lies in the fact that Pr(B|E1) = Pr(B & E1) / Pr(E1). However within the textbook, they only seem to be calculating Pr(B|E1) *(I have taken the example of E1 here and this is the same case with E2 and E3)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you know which coin is biased, the coin tosses are independent; so
$$P(B|E_1)=P(H_1|E_1)\cdot P(H_2|E_1)\cdot P(T_3|E_1)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$
where event $H_1$ = first coin landed on heads, etc.

Comment: Thank you! this helps a fair bit!